# Does OpenLDAP supports inheritance?

Tags: ldap, openldap, phpldapadmin

I have OU=people and 4 other groups like apple,mango,grape,orange. Now if i do OU=people is a member of CN=apple.

can OU=people users will get same privileges as like CN=apple ? I know little about Active directory LDAP service. There inheritance is possible. What about in OpenLDAP ? can i do OU=people is a memberof all 4 groups ?

Thanks

Comment: OpenLDAP doesn't aupoort inheritance from parent objects.

Answer (score 1):

The type of automatic inheritance you're talking about isn't built-in to OpenLDAP but there are two options you could use instead:

- [ACL sets](http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/1133.html), which give a very powerful way to define access rules. [Also see here](http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/1134.html)
- Dynamic Groups, using the memberURL attribute and either the [DynGroup](http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/1199.html) or [DynList](http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/1209.html) overlay